# Why does the following line crash ibtool?

Tags: xcode, xib, xcode6.3, ibtool

By removing code and trail and error, I found the following line in my .xib file crashes ibtool in Xcode 6.3.1.

```
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" style="UICTFontTextStyleHeadline"/>
```

Within the following block:

```
        <navigationController id="9" customClass="CustomNavigationController">
            <extendedEdge key="edgesForExtendedLayout"/>
            <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics" statusBarStyle="blackOpaque"/>
            <simulatedNavigationBarMetrics key="simulatedTopBarMetrics" translucent="NO" prompted="NO"/>
            <navigationBar key="navigationBar" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" barStyle="black" translucent="NO" id="11">
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.33333333333333331" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                <color key="tintColor" red="0.52042670701978977" green="0.78835227272727271" blue="0.33819077917403134" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                <textAttributes key="titleTextAttributes">
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" style="UICTFontTextStyleHeadline"/>
                    <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </textAttributes>
            </navigationBar>
            <viewControllers>
                <viewController nibName="RootViewController" id="13" customClass="RootViewController">
                    <extendedEdge key="edgesForExtendedLayout"/>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="14">
                        <nil key="title"/>
                    </navigationItem>
                </viewController>
            </viewControllers>
        </navigationController>
```

Is there another way to get the same functionality without crashing ibtool. This project is fairly old, is something I'm doing obsolete?